# How can I convert mp4 and mkv to 3gp?

Tags: command-line, conversion, avconv

I've a directory with 28 mp4's and 2 mkv's. I want to convert them all to 3gp using avconv. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

`avconv` doesn't support `3gp` codec, Check the list of supported codes by:

```
avconv -codecs
```

you need to install the non free/restricted packages of ffmpeg:

```
sudo apt-get install libavcodec-extra-53 libavformat-extra-53 libavutil-extra-51
```

using `ffmpeg`:

Now to convert:

```
ffmpeg -y -i movie.mp4 \
       -r 20 -s 352x288 -b 400k -acodec aac -strict experimental \
       -ac 1 -ar 8000 -ab 24k movie.3gp
```

To run this on all mp4 and mkv files in the current directory:

```
for file in *mp4 *mkv; do
    ffmpeg -y -i "$file" -r 20 -s 352x288 -b 400k \
   -acodec aac -strict experimental -ac 1 -ar 8000 \
   -ab 24k "${i%.*}".3gp
done
```

Or if you prefer some GUI apps take a look on [winFF](http://winff.org/html_new/).

To install in Ubuntu:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:paul-climbing/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install winff
```

Comment: In 14.04 there is no FFmpeg, it's in 15.04/15.10 but there are no extra packages for it. The extra packages are for libav (avconv), not ffmpeg. avconv  can convert to .3gp though user may be better off with winff than your generic command

Comment: You should also get straight that 3pg is a format, not a codec

Answer (score 0):

I would install and use [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/) just follow the download link. Handbrake lets you queue a work load; have a look at this [tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/199993/converting-videos-by-the-batch-with-handbrake/).